# How to get image upload date and display color gradient to show newest uploads

Tags: php, css

Let me start off by explaining my vision: So on my local site I have image1 and image2. I upload both to the remote site, and in the right hand corner there is a colored dot which is bright green. Now 3 hours later, I upload from local to remote again, but with image3, and now the site displays a slightly diluted green for image1 and image 2, but a bright green for image3.

NEWER [image] OLDER

In this way, as I add more images, the oldest will have a white dot in the top right corner and the newer ones will have brighter green dots. How can this be done if the creation date of the photo is different from the upload date? That is, if an image was taken yesterday and another the day before that, if I upload the one from the day before yesterday first, and then the one from yesterday, how do I get them to display in order of upload date?

The images themselves are sorted by name, so you could have a white dot first and then a green.

---

```
<?php foreach(glob('path/to/file/*.jpg') as $path){$arr[filectime($path)]=$path;}?>
```

Not sure how to get an effective gradient from `$arr`'s keys(UNIX times)...

Comment: I would dynamicly create the dot when displaying the image, dependig on file-upload time (I suppose you have that stored in a db?)

Comment: you want that dot IN the image? or as html element?

Comment: Can the exiftool date be different than the file creation date?

Comment: @Jeff, an overlay, _i.e._, `position:absolute; ... position:relative;`

Answer (score 1):

There are some usefull functions that you can resolve your problem:

[scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) — List files and directories inside the specified path
[filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) — Gets file modification time
[filectime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) — Gets inode change time of file 
[fileatime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) — Gets last access time of file
[stat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) — Gives information about a file